# perl programming to make function calls

Tags: perl, function

I want to call a function from my program.So can I save the function in another file instead of mixing with the script from where I am calling the function.If so ,with what name should I save the file with function.Please help..

Comment: File name doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a module. Here is a small module:

File `Foo.pm`

```
# declare a namespace
package Foo;

# always use these, they help you find errors
use strict; use warnings;

sub foo {
  print "Hello, this is Foo\n";
}

# a true value as last statement.
1;
```

You place that file into the same directory as your script:

File `script.pl`:

```
use strict; use warnings;

# load the module
use Foo;

Foo::foo(); # invoke the function via the fully qualified name
```

To create nicer modules, you'll probably look into object orientation, or the `Exporter` module.